# Hiding page numbers for in-line citations

Tags: formatting, citing

When I create citations, I use the `\cite[p.<somenumber>]{myCitation}` format as it allows me to track where the information came from if I need to go back and reference it.  I find it quite useful when working on a paper with others, however, in the final version I want to hide the page numbers for in-line citations.  Is there an option I can set that will achieve this so I don't have to delete the page numbers manually?  This would allow me to preview the final draft then switch back to draft mode easily.

Here's an example of my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[]{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{someTitle}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

someText~\cite[p.2]{_myCitation_2005}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{citations}

\end{document}
```

And my BibTeX:

```
@book{_myCitation_2005,
    address = {someAddress},
    edition = {3},
    title = {Some Citation},
    publisher = {some Publisher},
    month = sep,
    year = {2005}
}
```

I'd like a command that I can include in my preamble that will suppress all page numbers from being emitted in my in-line citations (they are not required for any citations in the final draft of the paper).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How will LaTeX know when the page numbers are required as part of the citation? Since this is frequently part of what you need to include, I'm not sure from your question how you are distinguishing between the just-for-me-draft cases and the required-part-of-citation cases in your document. If you could post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that would be helpful.

Comment: Sure.  I'll do that now and update my question.  Thanks for pointing me to the guide for your forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{\oldcite{#2}}
```

in your preamble to hide the page numbers. If you want the page numbers to be displayed, just comment those two lines. Be aware though that other citation commands like e.g. `\citeauthor` will still show the page numbers.